# getting error in using cv2.resize(image,(64,64))

Tags: opencv, resize-image

While using the code given below to resize multiple images

```
i=0

labels=[]

train_data = [] 

for img in (glob.glob(folder_path)):

   test_image = cv2.imread(img)

   labels.append(img[58:-4])

   test_image = cv2.resize(test_image, ( (272,272)))

   train_data.append(test_image)

   cv2.imwrite('C:/Users/HIMANSHU/Documents/Python Scripts/input/material_resize/'+labels[i]+'.jpeg',train_data[i])
   i=i+1
```

I get the following error:

> File "", line 7, in 
>       test_image = cv2.resize(test_image, ( (272,272)))
>
> error:
>   C:\bld\opencv_1510966172919\work\opencv-3.3.0\modules\imgproc\src\imgwarp.cpp:3483: error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function
>   cv::resize

Comment: Paani... once my edit is approved check code indentation if that fits yours on your computer.. not sure if I did the cv2.imwrite correct in your case. I might have correct by accident a mistake... thus... check.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the image was not read properly.

`error: (-215) ssize.width > 0 && ssize.height > 0 in function cv::resize` is telling you that an assertion that ensures the width and height of the image you are trying to resize are both greater than zero has failed. The most likely cause is that you have opened an image that could not be read or doesn't exist, and cv2 has returned an empty matrix. Your code works for me, as long as I only allow `img` to be the path of an actual image, when the path is not an image it fails.

A likely cause is your glob returning non-image files that cv2 cannot load into images.